# How do I hide an element defined as d-inline-block without making it it a block element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I hide an element defined as d-inline-block without making it it a block element? For example the bootstrap instruction for hiding an element on small devices is:

```
d-sm-none d-md-block
```

The problem is my element is already defined as d-inline-block on a medium device and the above instruction forces it into a block element on a medium device. I can't seem to hide an element on a small device without forcing it to be a block element on a medium device.

Comment: Does class="d-sm-none d-md-inline-block" not work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.